# Invalid client secret is provided when using correct and not expired secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-security, azure-secrets

I have Azure App Registration with active secret.
[image]

I'm trying to obtain token using v1.0 like below (`clientId` is an ID of the above App Registration)

```
$body = @{
    grant_type = 'client_credentials';
    client_id = $clientId;
    client_secret = $clientSecret;
    resource = $resourceId;
}

$aadResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$aadtenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

After regenerating credential using `az ad app credential reset --id XXX` everything works as expected - token is properly obtained.

However, in Azure Devops I got the following error while getting values from KV
[image]

Then I'm going to Azure Devops Service Connection and with `edit`, `verify` and `save` I'm able to connect with KV without any further changes.
[image]

However, this action breaks initially working get of token (as described above).

I'm 100% sure:

1. Password is correct
2. I'm really using a password, not its id
3. Encoding password doesn't help
4. There is no other action except `verify` service connection
5. I'm using [Failed to obtain the JWT by using the service principal client ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops) as a reference to Service Connections

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

After regenerating the client secret with `az ad app credential reset --id XXX`, I suppose you should get the error as below when you click the `Verify` in your service connection `Azure Resource Manager using service principal (automatic)`.

[image]

As shown on the service connection page, you created it with the automatic way, if you regenerate the client secret, you need to create a new service connection with the manual way to solve the issue.

[image]

You can obtain the values on the keyvault page and your AAD App page. For the `Service principal key`, it is the client secret you regenerated, you could not get it again if you didn't save it, if so, you need to regenerate a new one.

[image]

[image]

After fixing the values, verify and save.

[image]

Then use the new service connection in the `AzureKeyVault@2` task, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: What are the correct steps when having an automatic service connection and client secret expires? I see it as a common scenario. I have dozens of usages of my automatic service connection and changing all of them would be really painful.

Comment: @db_k Unfortunately, it is not supported to change the client secret used in the automatic one currently, as you can see there are just three options. I recommend you to request the feature here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21&preview2=true

Comment: Hey @JoyWang - is this still the case with the automatic method?